# How to find integral of the form $e^xf(x)$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I always face trouble with these type of integrals.

I need to find $$\int{e^x \frac{x(\cos x -\sin x)-\sin x}{x^2}}dx$$

My problem would be solved if can express $f(x)$ like $g(x)+g'(x)$ but identifying $g(x)$ by trial and error method is sometimes tedious.Is there any easier approach?

Comment: Your integral seems to be non-elementary. Since
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x\cos x}{x}=e^x\frac{x(\cos x-\sin x)-\color{red}\cos x}{x^2}
$$and$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x\sin x}{x}=e^x\frac{x(\cos x\color{red}+\sin x)-\sin x}{x^2}
$$you might have a typo.

Comment: Adding subtracting $cosx$ would help

Comment: @mickep na...i checked my book...its that only..

Comment: Then I'm curious about the answer in the book (if given)...

Comment: @Mickep I think you are right.My book must be having a mistake.

Comment: this kind of integral has no solution in the known elementary functions

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, I do not think that there is a solution in terms of elementary functions.

However, the problem can be approached using $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}\right)\qquad \sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2} i \left(e^{i x}-e^{-i x}\right)$$ So, the numerator of the integrand becomes$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{(1-i) x}
   x+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{(1+i) x} x-\frac{1}{2} i e^{(1-i)
   x}+\frac{1}{2} i e^{(1+i) x}$$ and we are then left with integrals looking like$$I=\int \frac{e^{\alpha x}} x \, dx\qquad J=\int \frac{e^{\alpha x}}{x^2} \, dx$$ Changing variable $\alpha x=y$ then makes $$I=\int \frac{e^y}{y}\,dy=\text{Ei}(y)$$ $$J= \alpha\int\frac{  e^y}{y^2}\,dy=\alpha  \left(\text{Ei}(y)-\frac{e^y}{y}\right)$$ where appears the exponential integral function (for the computation of $J$, one integration by parts is needed).

Using these last results and back to $x$ $$\int{e^x \frac{x(\cos x -\sin x)-\sin x}{x^2}}\, dx=i \Big(\text{Ei}((1+i) x)- \text{Ei}((1-i) x)\Big)+\frac{e^x \sin (x)}{x}$$

**Edit**

Looking at $$\int e^x\frac{ x (\cos (x)\pm \sin (x))\pm  \sin (x)}{x^2}\,dx$$ the only combination which leads to elementary functions is the combination $(+,-)$ and then $$\int e^x\frac{ x (\cos (x)+ \sin (x))-  \sin (x)}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{ \sin (x)}{x}e^x$$ So, one more typo in a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The typo can be not in the signs of the fraction but in the sign of the argument of the exponential function, that is if we replace $e^{x}$ by $e^{-x}$ the fraction remains as it is and the answer would be 
$$\frac{ \sin (x)}{x}e^{-x}+C,$$ since 
$$\int e^{-x}\frac{ x (\cos (x)- \sin (x))-  \sin (x)}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{ \sin (x)}{x}e^{-x}+C
$$ which can be obtained easly by parts.

I think it is obvious to see that the fraction is nothing but $$f^\prime(x)-f(x)$$ where $f(x)$ is the product $f(x)=(\frac{1}{x}) \sin(x).$ Recall $ (\frac{1}{x})^\prime=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.